# Fix Ubuntu cannot interract after login Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, xrandr

After having fullscreen issue even after installing install the Guest Additions I fallowed steps on different forums. One caused me to have a black screen after login using the command `xrandr` like so :

`xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1024x768`

After rebooting, now I have a black screen after login. When I try to changed the `xrandr` to something it was before 600x800 the command xrandr returns `Can't open display`.

Is there a solution, a file to remove/change or some command to use instead of get rid of my VM (I have many things I don't want to lose)

Using Virtual Box 6.1 and Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS

Here are the last commands I used :

```
sudo apt-get remove libcheese-gtk23
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
sudo apt-get -q -y -f build-dep virtualbox-ose-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-x11 virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
xrandr
xrandr --output VGA-1 --size 1024x768
```

Edit :

I upgraded to the latest Ubuntu 19.10 hoping it'll changed anything. Now the screen isn't black anymore but I cannot interact with it after login. Keyboard and mouse don't do anything even if the mouse is showing up.

**Fix**

I found a method [reinstall ubuntu-desktop](https://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/#:~:text=Well%2C%20since%20you%20are%20stuck,asked%20to%20enter%20your%20credentials.) which worked for me. Hope it could help others :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: What are the "steps on different forums"?

Comment: @Pilot6 I updated the question adding the command I used

Comment: This command won't stay after a reboot. There must be something else.

Comment: Is there a way to get the logs ?

Comment: `history` command.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to adjust the video settings from VirtualBox.  I know this is not a full answer but it is the only way I know to post pictures. Below you can see the settings I am using.  Adjust the Virtualization and Video Acceleration.  And adjust the kind of Graphics Controller. [image]

Comment: Thank you for answering. I already have the exact same configuration as you except my Ubuntu.vdi is 50 GB

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first setup the new mode.  Below is from some notes a while back. You will need to adjust everything for your own resolution.

To get the settings for the resolution, type the following at the terminal window

```
cvt 1440 900
```

Take the modeline info you will get and paste into the command below to give the graphics system the new resolution.

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900" 106.50 1440 1528 1672 1904 900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

Now add that mode to the current session

```
xrandr --addmode DVI-0 "1440x900"
```

Now output it to the display that you want.

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1440x900
```

NOTE:Once it works then you can write a shell script such as the one below and it will run at boot.

```
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1368x768_60.00" && xrandr --output VGA1 --mode  1368x768_60.00
```

Comment: I can't use `xrandr` because I cannot access the screen after login

Comment: Ok. For some reasons, now I have something on my screen but i cannot click anything and my keyboard doesn't do anything

Comment: Before you login you can try Control-Alt-F1 and get to the black and white screen.  Then run the commands above to add the mode.  Then lastly startx which will start the GUI.