# Ubuntu VirtualBox VM does not accept input after logging in

Tags: virtualbox, input

After successfully installing VBox Guest Additions, I can now change the screen resolution to whatever I like. Unfortunately, I now have another issue.

I can't type anything, I think it is not accepting any input from the keyboard. Clicking in the VM area just seems to disable the mouse and I can't escape the VM without using my touch screen (though Host+P probably would work too but I didn't try it).

Edit: Everything, mouse and keyboard, work before I log in. Once the desktop appears, I can't click on anything (cursor works) or type anything.

Edit 2: The first automatically opening window to appear is "System program problem detected / Do you want to report the problem now?", and in the taskbar I see Update-notifier.

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245909/fix-ubuntu-cannot-interract-after-login-virtualbox?rq=1 Solution here, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

[Fix Ubuntu cannot interract after login Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245909/fix-ubuntu-cannot-interract-after-login-virtualbox?rq=1)

Solution here, worked for me.

You need to choose "Advanced boot options for Ubuntu" in grub. I got grub to show up by resetting the Virtualbox while it was booting.

After choosing Advanced boot options, you can enable networking and then go to the root prompt. Then you can follow the steps in the link:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install unity
```